# SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO: Highlight variables

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Is there a way in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO to highlight all usage of variables when we click on a variable name?

Comment: Not natively, as far as I know.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745051/ssms-when-selecting-a-string-in-script-highlight-same-literals

Answer (score 2):

It might not work in all cases, but I find that using the `F2` button, which on my machine is mapped to 'View.EditLabel'. It allows me to highlight all of one 'type' things like aliases, variable names and others. Not perfect, but fits my purpose.

[image]

I still stand by the fact that it might not be perfect, but it does do what the original poster asked. If you want to see what this command is mapped to see the Options windows.

[image]

Comment: Can you describe how do I get this 'View.EditLabel' ?

Comment: I also have F2 globally mapped to 'View.EditLabel' by default. Still, when I select text and press F2 I get no highlighting.

Comment: It does not work for free text. As I mentioned above it works for things like aliases and variables.

Comment: @PriteshAcharya Go to the Tools menu and click Options. Under Environment, click on Keyboard. In the text box under "Show commands containing" type in View.EditLabel and you will see what the command is mapped to.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me running `SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1` (even for aliases and variables, double checked the shortcut mapping)

Answer (score 2):

In the last version of SSMS (currently version 17.1), select the text and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> .

[image: Example use of Ctrl+F]

Comment: This is a nice feature you can find in some MS products like VS and MMS. But it is not highlighting variables, it's just part of the text find feature

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not such feature on SSMS

Answer (score -3):

This has been added in SSMS 2016. 
Available for download from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: I have `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (13.0.16000.28)`. I get no highlighting when selecting text.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as well...