# SSMS: When selecting a string in script highlight same literals

Tags: ssms

In Visual Studio when I select any literal it will highlight all the occurrences of the same literal. Is there a similar functionality in SQL Server Management Studio.

Say I have My_Temp_Table in my script. When selecting the literal "My_Temp_Table" I would like SSMS to highlight every instance of the "My_Temp_Table" string in my script.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I would like SSMS to highlight all occurrences of the highlighted item - just like Notepad++ does. I double-clicked the word THAT and Notepad++ highlights all occurrences of that item. THen I did the same thing for the word IS. - See images. >>>>**Can SSMS do that too?** [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLFGg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLFGg.png)
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4xqA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4xqA.png)

Comment: Newest SSMS highlights the text you search for. So select a text, press ctrl+f and it should highlight any matches.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899826/sql-server-management-studio-highlight-variables

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no such feature on SSMS.

I tried to look for the same feature as well. CTRL + F is our only good options to look for the same name literals.

Answer (score 2):

I've not yet found any such setting (and it's something I *really* miss whenever I switch from Visual Studio to SSMS), but I've stumbled across a few shortcuts on [the Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15#search-keyboard-shortcuts) that expand on the answer by @willy-david-jr:

- Display the Find dialog box: `CTRL+F`
- Find the next occurrence of the previous search text: `F3`
- Find the previous occurrence of the search text: `SHIFT+F3`
- Find the next occurrence of the currently selected text: `CTRL+F3`
- Find the previous occurrence of the currently selected text: `CTRL+SHIFT+F3`

Using these in conjunction with cursor position, you can at least more easily cycle through occurrences of the literal in the current editor window. They all highlight matches, and you don't even need to double-click the literal you want to search - simply having the caret in the string when you press the shortcut is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Using SSMS 18.12.1 in March 2023

I tried the following and it highlights all occurrences:

1. Select the text you want to fin
2. Type Ctrl+F3

Comment: LOL for me this turned up the speaker volume O)

Comment: I had to hit CTRL-fn-F3 where fn is a button on the laptop